# Difference in initializing variable normally and by object

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code:

```
var Module = (function () {
   var parameters = {};
   var foo = function() {
      parameters = {'aaa': 'aaa2'};
      // Module.parameters = {'aaa': 'aaa2'};
   }; 
   return {
      foo: foo
   };
})();
var Module2 = (function () {
   var bar = function() {
      console.log(Module.parameters);
   };
   return {
      bar: bar
   };
})();
```

When I initialize parameters like this and then access it from `Module2` I get empty object.

But when I initialize it with `Module.parameters` I get the proper results.

Where this difference comes from?

Comment: `Module.parameters` is undefined, did you mean `Module.foo`? Also using capitalization seems to imply a class, which `Module` most definitely is not.

Comment: Technically speaking, Javascript doesn't even have classes... unless EC6 put them in? /oblivious

Comment: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/

Refer this link it will clear your doubt

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining something with var that is local variable that means you can access that variable with in the function where you declared it. When you define something like module.foo = "value" than that is member of an object. If you can access the object you also can access member

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplify this a little. Imagine you had

```
var x = 42;
var obj = {
  y: 21,
};
```

You are currently doing the equivalent to accessing `obj.x`. But `obj` doesn't have such a property. It only has the property `y`. `x` is just a variable, completely independent from `obj`.

That's the same in your case with `parameters` and `foo`. The object you are returning

```
return {
   foo: foo
};
```

only has a single property `foo`. `parameters` is a variable that has nothing to do with the object.

Assigning to `Module.parameters` "works" because you are mutating that very object you return, adding a new property. It would be equivalent to

```
obj.x = 'something';
```

in my example.